# How can I tell what arima model this code is running?

Tags: r, arima

I'm reading over some R code, and I've come across a line that where the function prototype doesn't seem to match what I've seen in the library's api (`fabletools`).

```
fitted_model = a_time_series %>%
filter(date <= tsibble::year(someyear)) %>%
fabletools::model(arima = ARIMA(time)
```

...Where time is a column from a a_time_series. How do I tell what arima model this is using?

(e.g. arima(1,1,1) or arima(0,1,1) ,etc)

I've checked this [documentation](https://fable.tidyverts.org/reference/ARIMA.html) however, the function prototypes don't seem to match.

Comment: Hello Jaigus ARIMA will calculate the coefficients following something very similar to the forecast package auto.arima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the ARIMA output by looking at the formatted output in the console. If you need to obtain this display as text, you can use the `format()` function.

```r
library(fable)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)
tourism %>% 
  group_by(Purpose) %>% 
  summarise(Trips = sum(Trips)) %>% 
  model(auto_arima = ARIMA(Trips)) %>% 
  mutate(format(auto_arima))
#> # A mable: 4 x 3
#> # Key:     Purpose [4]
#>   Purpose                auto_arima `format(auto_arima)`    
#>   <chr>                     <model> <chr>                   
#> 1 Business <ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[4]> <ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[4]>
#> 2 Holiday  <ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[4]> <ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)[4]>
#> 3 Other    <ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,0,0)[4]> <ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,0,0)[4]>
#> 4 Visiting <ARIMA(1,0,1)(2,1,0)[4]> <ARIMA(1,0,1)(2,1,0)[4]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
#>  os       Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS          
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language en_AU:en                    
#>  collate  en_AU.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_AU.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Australia/Melbourne         
#>  date     2020-06-12                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package        * version    date       lib source                            
#>  anytime          0.3.7      2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  assertthat       0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  backports        1.1.7      2020-05-13 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  callr            3.4.3      2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  cli              2.0.2      2020-02-28 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  colorspace       1.4-1      2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  crayon           1.3.4      2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  desc             1.2.0      2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  devtools         2.2.2      2020-02-17 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  digest           0.6.25     2020-02-23 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  distributional   0.1.0.9000 2020-06-10 [1] local                             
#>  dplyr          * 1.0.0      2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  ellipsis         0.3.1      2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  evaluate         0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  fable          * 0.2.1      2020-06-11 [1] local                             
#>  fabletools     * 0.2.0      2020-06-11 [1] local                             
#>  fansi            0.4.1      2020-01-08 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  farver           2.0.3      2020-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  feasts           0.1.4      2020-06-04 [1] local                             
#>  fs               1.4.1      2020-04-04 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  generics         0.0.2      2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  ggplot2          3.3.1      2020-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  glue             1.4.1.9000 2020-05-26 [1] Github (tidyverse/glue@a605000)   
#>  gtable           0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  highr            0.8        2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  htmltools        0.4.0      2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  knitr            1.28       2020-02-06 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  lattice          0.20-38    2018-11-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  lifecycle        0.2.0.9000 2020-03-19 [1] Github (r-lib/lifecycle@355dcba)  
#>  lubridate        1.7.8      2020-04-06 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  magrittr         1.5        2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  memoise          1.1.0      2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  munsell          0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  nlme             3.1-142    2019-11-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  pillar           1.4.4      2020-05-25 [1] Github (r-lib/pillar@2f5ad11)     
#>  pkgbuild         1.0.8      2020-05-07 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  pkgconfig        2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  pkgload          1.1.0      2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  prettyunits      1.1.1      2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  processx         3.4.2      2020-02-09 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  progressr        0.6.0      2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  ps               1.3.3      2020-05-08 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  purrr            0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  R6               2.4.1      2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  Rcpp             1.0.4.6    2020-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  remotes          2.1.1      2020-02-15 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  rlang            0.4.6.9000 2020-05-20 [1] Github (r-lib/rlang@691b5a8)      
#>  rmarkdown        2.1        2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  rprojroot        1.3-2      2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  scales           1.1.1      2020-05-11 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  sessioninfo      1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  stringi          1.4.6      2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)                    
#>  stringr          1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  testthat         2.3.2      2020-03-02 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  tibble           3.0.1      2020-04-20 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  tidyr            1.1.0      2020-05-20 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  tidyselect       1.1.0      2020-05-11 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  tsibble        * 0.9.0      2020-06-02 [1] Github (tidyverts/tsibble@c837e83)
#>  urca             1.3-0      2016-09-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  usethis          1.5.1.9000 2020-01-31 [1] Github (r-lib/usethis@7d8b066)    
#>  utf8             1.1.4      2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                    
#>  vctrs            0.3.0.9000 2020-05-28 [1] Github (r-lib/vctrs@373e1ce)      
#>  withr            2.2.0      2020-04-20 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  xfun             0.13       2020-04-13 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.3)                    
#>  yaml             2.2.1      2020-02-01 [1] RSPM (R 3.6.2)                    
#> 
#> [1] /home/mitchell/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6
#> [2] /opt/R/3.6.2/lib/R/library
```